# How to customize QModbusDataUnit to send hex values in modbus?

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qt-creator, modbus

I would need to customize the `QModbusDataUnit` by sending custom hex via modbus, below my code, I'm trying to customize the post but I do not understand how to do it.

I should send the following values: `0x01,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xE0,0x0B`

```
   void connessione::clickButton(){

  QModbusDataUnit readUnit(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 1, QVector<quint16>({0x01,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xE0,0x0B}));
        qDebug() << "readUnit" << clientX->state();

        if (auto *reply = clientX->sendReadRequest(readUnit, 255)) // client id 255
        {
            if (!reply->isFinished())
            {
                // connect the finished signal of the request to your read slot
                qDebug() << "connected" << reply->errorString();
                connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, this, &connessione::readReady);
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "Errore" << reply->errorString();
                delete reply; // broadcast replies return immediately
            }
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Errore" << reply->errorString();
            // request error
        }
    }
```

but my response is:

> D/libmodbusMobile.so(15006): (null):0 ((null)): qt.modbus: (TCP
>   client) Sent TCP PDU: 0x0300080008 with tId: 0

where set 0x03 ? 
this is not right, it's not equal to my QVector send, how to solve ?

Comment: How if you specify the data size to a value greater than one, i.e. using `QModbusDataUnit readUnit(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 0, 7)` then call `setValue(0, 0x01), setValue(1, 0x03)...`? Or store the values to a `QVector<quint16>` then using the constructor `QModbusDataUnit(RegisterType type, int address, const QVector<quint16> &data)` to create the variable `readUnit`.

Comment: you tell me QModbusDataUnit readUnit(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 0, new QVector<qint16>(0,1,ecc)); ?

Comment: If you have `c++11` you can initialize the vector as `QVector<quint16>({0x01, 0x03, ...})`. Otherwise you need, `QVector<quint16> readUnit; readUnit.append(0x01), readUnit.append(0x03) ...`.

Comment: I've edit my answer and set vector, nut the buffer that I send not equal a Qvector

Comment: The second parameter is an address so I think it should be 0 instead of 8.

Comment: my channel is 1, but the result not change

Comment: I'm little bit confused now. Do you want to `send` the data (client send a *write* request) or you want to `receive` the data(client read a data from certain server)? In your code, you're using `sendReadRequest` which is the second. If you want to `send`, I think you need `sendWriteRequest`.

Comment: My target is send bytes to wifi board with qt. How do it ?

Comment: Have you tried `sendWriteRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to test a QModbusDataUnit as follows:

```
QModbusDataUnit myUnit;
QModbusDataUnit::RegisterType myType;
myType = static_cast<QModbusDataUnit::RegisterType>(0x04);
myUnit = QModbusDataUnit(myType,0x0c,0x03);
cout << hex;
cout << myUnit.registerType() << endl;
cout << myUnit.startAddress() << endl;
```

Notes:

To use “cout” in a console QT application;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

To create a QT Modbus console application include the following in the .pro file;

```
QT += serialbus widgets
qtConfig(modbus-serialport): QT += serialport

TARGET = modbusserver
```